# Error connecting to FTP server | C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to upload a simple txt file to an exsisting ftp server. It looks like I can connect but when I get to

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

or

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I get an error:

> "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

How can I know if the error is due to the code or the server and how do I fix this problem?

My code:

```
Console.Write("FTP Server: ");
string ftpServer = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("User name: ");
string userName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Password: ");
string password = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);


// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

try
{
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Web error: {err}");
}

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();
```